# Node.js SSL / HTTPS request to api.bitbucket.org gets weird ssl error

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I am getting this weird error:

```
Making request to bitbucket api at path: /2.0/repositories/interos/eco-system-globe/commit/116c82c81b8d3e1b8c2fd3f352510fd09e66a02e
***Request stream error***: Error: write EPROTO 139717438125888:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:83:16) {
  errno: 'EPROTO',
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

the code I have is simply:

```
 const pth = `/2.0/repositories/${fullRepoName}/commit/${sha}`;

  console.log('Making request to bitbucket api at path:',pth);

  const newReq = https.get({  // formerly get
    protocol: 'https:',
    port: 80,
    hostname: 'api.bitbucket.org',
    path: pth,
    headers: {

      'Authorization': `Basic ${bitbucketBase64}`,
      'Auth': `Basic ${bitbucketBase64}`
    }

  }, r => {


    const v = {
      data: ''
    };

    r.on('data', d => {
      v.data += String(d || '');
    });

    r.once('end', () => {

      console.log('response ended:', r.statusCode);
      cb(null, v);

    });

  });


  newReq.once('error', e => {
    console.error('***Request stream error***:', e);
  });

  // newReq.write(stringified);
  newReq.end();
```

anyone have an idea what that's about? I am on Node.js version **12.2.0**

Comment: You are using HTTPS on port 80. Shouldn't it be 443?

Comment: Yeah that was it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had `port: 80` but it should be `port: 443` ... for SSL that's the default, so you can just omit the port argument.